# Adding links to another cell using the xlwt module for Python

Tags: python, xlwt

I am exporting some information to an excel workbook using the awesome xlwt module for Python. I know that I can have a certain cell contain a hyperlink that points to an external site like this:

```
    from xlwt import Workbook, Formula
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.add_sheet('testing links')
    link = 'HYPERLINK("http://stackoverflow.com/"; "SO")'
    sheet.write(0, 0, Formula(link))
    wb.save("testbk.xls")
```

However, what I actually want to do is something like "drilling through" the document. I want cell A1 from "sheet1" to point to cell F5 in "sheet3" for example.

Does someone know if what I am asking is possible; and if so, what syntax I must use to accomplish that?

Comment: Can't you just use the same method as above with whatever the syntax would be within excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [answered on the python-excel forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/python-excel/zLMIxnIUwDI):

STW to find out how a user does it in Excel:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet3!F5","some text")
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want something like this:

```
# to get to a different sheet in XL, use the sheet name, an !, and then the 
# cell coordinates. In this case, you're going to sheet3, cell F3
link = 'sheet3!F3'
# This is still a formula, so you should link it as such.
sheet.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula(link))
```

Comment: Well, the original poster specifically asked for a hyperlink, not just a formula using another cell.

Comment: getting FormulaParseException: can't parse formula

Answer (score 2):

If you have created the sheet like this:

```
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('Type ' + str(i))
```

You may find the only way to get the hyperlink to work is to add a single quote (escaped)

```
link = 'HYPERLINK("#\'Type '+ str(i) + '\'!A1", "Link")'
sheet.write(0, 1, xlwt.Formula(link))
```

Comment: This only covers the case where a sheet name contains a space. A sheet name like `O'Reilly's data` needs to be input as `'O''Reilly''s data` i.e. follow the same process as for a string literal in SQL: double every apostrophe in the string then add an apostrophe at the start and end. This is best done with `xlwt.Utils.quote_sheet_name(unquoted_sheet_name)` which does the required quoting and also checks the input for validity. Rationale for checking is that it's better to get a sensible error message at file creation time than a garbled message from Excel at (later) file open time.